# Build an array with input from tableviewcell UITextfield

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a tableview with dynamical amount of cells, based on an array who is build up by a JSON.

```
tableData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataWebService options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

This little line gets all the data I need to build my tableview.

In the tableview I have a textfield in every cell with predefined text from my JSON. The user can change this value before he proceed to the next segue (storyboard).

The question is how I can store this usertyped values in an array an replace the excisting values in my `tableData` array before I send this arraobject to the next segue.

And keep in mind that the user input must not change when the user scroll in the tableview.

Maybe this is basic, but I cannot figure a nice way to do this.

This is an example of the JSON.

```
(
    {
    defaultval = 8;
    dtype = long;
    id = "@franr";
    label = "Faktura nr.";
},
    {
    defaultval = 8;
    dtype = long;
    id = "@tilnr";
    label = "Til faktura";
}
```

The tableview look like this: 
(I cannot post images)

Fra faktura 8
Til faktura 8

The user can change the values (number 8) to any numbers. So I need to replace the numbers of defaultVal in my JSON array.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since its a UITEXTFIELD, you can use OnTextChange Event

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

or

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range     
                  replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

, or lose focus

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

please keep in mind you need to set the delegate of the textfield to self & add the respective protocals.

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep the data after scrolling, you should modify the data source (the array) after each input from the user. You can do dis in the UITextFieldDelegate's `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method (of course, you have to be the delegate for each text field: `textField.delegate = self;`).
You should also implement a UIScrollViewDelegate method, for dismissing the keyboard when the table begins to scroll (e.g. `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:`).

**EDIT:**

Your array must be containing NSDictionaries, which are not mutable, so I recommend, you create your own class having those attributes (defaultval, dtype ...), so you can edit the data source. I don't think you can modify your array the way it is now.

The code with custom object would be something like:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    UITableViewCell *cell = textField.superview.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    MyObject *currentObject = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    currentObject.defaultVal = textField.text.intValue;
}
```

Comment: Okei. But how do I update the main array with the new values from te user input?

Comment: I see. I will give it a try and respond when I have tested. Thanks.